# Is it possible to import a python file in Google Colab which itself imports a GitHub repository to function?

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I'm experimenting with the integration of Google Colab, GitHub, and Google Drive. One of the things I want to be able to do is create files, Gists in particular but also entire repos potentially, which reference other Gists and repos as dependencies. For a toy example I've been using to experiment, I have a simple .py script that runs the following:

```
import random

def dice_roll():
  roll = random.randint(1,6)
  return roll
```

This simply returns an integer between 1 and 6. But suppose I take this file, saved as a Gist, and import it into Colab so I can use it. As a whole, that small import script would look something like this:

```
# Clone the entire repo.
!git clone -l -s https://gist.github.com/dcdesmond/28276a70d5d5611d3e0f4f5717eca535 cloned-repo

# Change directory into cloned repo
%cd cloned-repo

# List repo contents
!ls
```

This works perfectly fine, and in the Colab notebook cell where it runs, the output will be:

```
Cloning into 'cloned-repo'...
warning: --local is ignored
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
/content/cloned-repo
dice_roll.py
```

Thus, if

```
import dice_roll
dice_roll.dice_roll()
```

is run in the next cell, it will output an integer between 1 and 6. But this output depends on a module contained in an external, GitHub Gist. So if I wanted to begin layering my Gists (or even an entire repo, over time) so that the modules would automatically reach out to the GitHub link for the required dependencies, it's reasonable to think I could download all of the above as a composite .py file, which would run as a single script (call it `dice_roller.py`) as below:

```
# Clone the entire repo.
!git clone -l -s https://gist.github.com/dcdesmond/28276a70d5d5611d3e0f4f5717eca535 cloned-repo

# Change directory into cloned repo
%cd cloned-repo

# List repo contents
!ls

import dice_roll
dice_roll.dice_roll()
```

and then repeat the process: clone this composite .py file in a Colab notebook and run it (and all of its layered dependencies), which would hypothetically produce the same output (an integer between 1 and 6), or in a more complex scenario, a network of referenced repositories and their files.

But if I save this all into a single `dice_roller.py` script, saved as a Gist repo and clone that Gist in the same way:

```
!git clone -l -s https://gist.github.com/dcdesmond/bda461a04705ab570747a4e7685b0372 cloned-repo
%cd cloned-repo
!ls
```

With the same working output:

```
Cloning into 'cloned-repo'...
warning: --local is ignored
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
/content/cloned-repo
dice_roller.py
```

Then I am met with a syntax parsing error, because python cannot read the `git clone` commands:

```
import dice_roller
```

```
  File "/content/cloned-repo/cloned-repo/dice_roller.py", line 12
    !git clone -l -s https://gist.github.com/dcdesmond/28276a70d5d5611d3e0f4f5717eca535 cloned-repo
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Are there any pythonic ways of automatically interacting with repositories and their contents between scripts in a way that Colab would accommodate?

I may be reinventing the wheel here if there is another way to accomplish this goal of writing scripts that extract files contained in other repositories and then uses them. It seems to me to be a conflict between file system navigation/commands and python itself, rather than a Google Colab problem. Since Colab is just IPython/Jupyter online, I'd imagine someone has encountered a similar problem locally. If there is another way to think about the problem so that I would only need to import one repo or one file (without needing to replicate ad hoc repos with all of the content I might want), that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace `!` and `%cd` with normal Python equivalents.

- ! becomes getoutput
- %cd becomes os.chdir("...")

Here's the result

```py
%%writefile dice_roller2.py
import os
from subprocess import getoutput
getoutput("git clone -l -s https://gist.github.com/dcdesmond/28276a70d5d5611d3e0f4f5717eca535 cloned-repo")
os.chdir('cloned-repo')
import dice_roll
print(dice_roll.dice_roll())
```

Here's a runnable [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UhEn05GLmTw-6F_SPtV8PWnxA7FBRC7L).